# Al intentar acceder a propiedad, aparece el error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Estoy realizando un simple CRUD con Vue Js y Laravel 8. Al momento de hacer una petición GET para obtener el listado de objetos no tengo ningún problema, pero cuando hago una búsqueda unitaria mediante el id, me arroja el siguiente error:

> `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined`

Adjunto código para detallar más la explicación.

En este archivo tengo las peticiones (departments.js)

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';

export default function useDepartments(){
    const departments = ref([])
    const department = ref([])
    const router = useRouter()
    const errors = ref('')

    const getDepartments = async () => {
        let response = await axios.get('/api/departments')
        departments.value = response.data.data;
    }

    const getDepartment = async (id) => {
        let response = await axios.get('/api/departments/' + id)
        department.value = response.data.data;
    }
    
    const storeDepartment = async (data) => {
        errors.value = ''
        try {
            await axios.post('/api/departments', data)
            await router.push({ name: 'departments.index' })
        } catch(e) {
            if (e.response.status === 422) {
                errors.value = e.response.data.errors
            }
        }
    }
    
    const destroyDepartments = async (id) => {
        await axios.delete('/api/departments/' + id)
    }

    return {
        departments,
        errors,
        getDepartment,
        getDepartments,
        storeDepartment,
        destroyDepartments
    };
}
```

En este archivo es donde me arroja el error al momento de poner la información en el formulario (DepartmentsEdit.vue)

```
<template>
    <div v-if="errors">
        <div v-for="(v, k) in errors" :key="k" >
            <p v-for="error in v" :key="error">
                {{ error }}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <form v-on:submit.prevent="saveDepartment">
            <label for="">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" v-model="department.name">
            <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </form>   
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import useDepartments from '../../composables/departments';
    import { onMounted } from 'vue';

    export default {
        props: {
            id: {
                required: true,
                type: String
            }
        },
        
        setup(props) {

            const { department, getDepartment } = useDepartments()
            
            onMounted(getDepartment(props.id))
            
            return {
                department
                /* saveDepartment */
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

La única diferencia es el uso de props entre el get para listar y el get para individual, aparte de eso me arroja unos warnings la consola que no sé si tengan algo que ver.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya estuve haciendo depuración de código para ver dónde está el error y si puedo acceder a la variable desde el archivo departments.js mediante `console.log`, pero no logro mostrar la información en el formulario.

Comment: Si en DepartamentsEdit.vue, en lugar de toooodo el template con el v-if, pones {{departament}}, que te muestra? Entiendo que puede tener una propiedad departament.name, pero sospecho que si no creas una variable para dicho valor no vas a poder hacer el doble binding con v-model. Probablemente si declaras un objeto departament (local) con las propiedades 
que necesitas (en data o setup), después del obtener el departamento de la base de datos, haces una copia en el objeto local, deberia andar sin problema

Comment: Por el tema de los warnings, dice que en los componentes App.vue y DepartamentsEdit.vue tenes llamadas a variables en el template (``open`` y ``errors`` respectivamente) que no están declaradas en el objeto return del setup